# How can I get my pictures to work so that they can only be clicked one time each time the game is played?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I want one picture to be clicked and that is all, then I want it to run the level again. Eventually I'll want to randomise what picture is behind the pots but if that is too hard to do then don't worry for now.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
lives=3
score=0

 document.write("Lives:",lives,"<br>");

 document.write("Score:",score);

function clickMeIDFunction(theElementID){
        var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
        theElement.src = "nope.gif";

 }
 function clickMeIDFunction2(theElementID){
        var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
        theElement.src = 'nope.gif';
 }
 function clickMeIDFunction3(theElementID){
        var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
        theElement.src = "gold-bar-icon.png";
 }

 if (lives=0){
     document.write("Game over!");
 }

</script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img id="pot1" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction('pot1')">
<img id="pot2" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction2('pot2')">
<img id="pot3" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction3('pot3')">
</center>
</div>`enter code here`
```

Comment: "don't worry for now"? that's easy for you to say.

Comment: It's just really confusing, don't understand programming that well :/

Comment: Nobody does at first—hang in there, you'll get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function : refreshGame like this:

```
function refreshGame(){
   for(var i = 1 ; i<=3 ; i++){
      document.getElementById('pot'+i).src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif";
   }
}
```

and call this function after each of your clickMeIDFunctionX functions like this :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
lives=3
score=0

 document.write("Lives:",lives,"<br>");

 document.write("Score:",score);

 function refreshGame(){
   for(var i = 1 ; i<=3 ; i++){
      document.getElementById('pot'+i).src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif";
   }
 }
function clickMeIDFunction(theElementID){
        var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
        theElement.src = "nope.gif";
        //Sleep here so that you can see the changes:
        setTimeout(refreshGame,1000);
        //SetTimeOut would call refresh game after 1 seconde.
 }
 function clickMeIDFunction2(theElementID){
        var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
        theElement.src = 'nope.gif';
        //Sleep here so that you can see the changes:
        setTimeout(refreshGame,1000);
        //SetTimeOut would call refresh game after 1 seconde.
 }
 function clickMeIDFunction3(theElementID){
        var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
        theElement.src = "gold-bar-icon.png";
        //Sleep here so that you can see the changes:
        setTimeout(refreshGame,1000);
        //SetTimeOut would call refresh game after 1 seconde.
 }

 if (lives=0){
     document.write("Game over!");
 }

</script>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><img id="pot1" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction('pot1')">
<img id="pot2" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction2('pot2')">
<img id="pot3" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction3('pot3')">
</center>
</div>`enter code here`
```

Not Sure about my edit because i didnt run this, their might be some syntaxe errors, but thats the global idea. 
Hope that helped you

Comment: Would that go before or after my other functions? Because at the moment nothing has changed :/ I'm so confused by this :/

Comment: Nothing has changed i'm afraid :/

Comment: sorry had a syntaxe error: its setTimeout not setTimeOut ^^' @David Tearse check again now

Comment: I was about to say actually I wanted it to stay showing that they'd lost or won and then said continue to the next level (which I can do) but this works rather well actually... thank you! Now I somehow have to try and randomise it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution from what I understood.

```
<p>Lives: <span id="lives"></span></p>
<p>Score: <span id="score"></span></p>
<p id="game_status"></p>
<p>
<img id="pot1" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction('pot1')">
<img id="pot2" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction2('pot2')">
<img id="pot3" src="imageedit_2_3920956067.gif" width="238" height="170" class="pot" onclick="clickMeIDFunction3('pot3')">
</p>


<script language="JavaScript">

    lives=3
    score=0

    function clickMeIDFunction(theElementID){
            var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
            theElement.src = "nope.gif";
            // decrease lives by 1 as it is a nope
            lives--;
            // call update_game_info so that it will update the lives and scores in the DOM
            update_game_info()
     }
     function clickMeIDFunction2(theElementID){
            var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
            theElement.src = 'nope.gif';
            // same as for clickMeIDFunction
            lives--;
            update_game_info()
     }
     function clickMeIDFunction3(theElementID){
            var theElement = document.getElementById(theElementID);
            theElement.src = "gold-bar-icon.png";
            // a correct click, so increase score by 1, do nothing to lives
            score++;
            // update the info in DOM
            update_game_info();
     }

     // Update the game info, reset/restart game if score is 0
     function update_game_info(){
        document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = lives;
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
        if (lives == 0){
            document.getElementById("game_status").innerHTML = "Game Over!";
            // Restart game
            // Reset lives and score as you desire
            // Randomize the pot picture
        }
     }

     update_game_info();

</script>
```

Comment: Would be better if you can explain the changes you made so he can understand them =)

Comment: This had definitely helped with the lives thank you! And the guy underneath helped with the restarting of the game :)